# Update Content-Control Text in Header and Footer using Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

To change the Content-Control Text in the Document Body I'm doing this:

```
var elements = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document
    .Descendants<SdtElement>()
    .Where(s => s.SdtProperties.ChildElements.Count > 0 && 
                s.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>()?.Val == contentControlTag);

foreach (var element in elements)
{
    if (element == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var elementText = element.Descendants<Text>();

    if (elementText != null)
    {
        var elementTextValue = elementText.FirstOrDefault();

        if (elementTextValue != null)
        {
            elementTextValue.Text = text;
        }
        elementText.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(t => t.Remove());
    }
}
```

Sadly this doesn't change the Header/Footer part.

I want to check each page's  header/Footer part for a specific Content-Control-Tag and change its text similar to the code above. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers and footers aren't in the `MainDocumentPart.Document`, they are subparts in the [`HeaderParts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.maindocumentpart.headerparts?view=openxml-2.8.1) and [`FooterParts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.maindocumentpart.footerparts?view=openxml-2.8.1) collections off the [`MainDocumentPart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.maindocumentpart?view=openxml-2.8.1).  So you'll need to process each part separately.  Fortunately, all of the parts share a common base class, [`OpenXmlPart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpart?view=openxml-2.8.1), so you can put them together into a list and process them in a loop.  Since you'll be dealing with the base class, you'll need to use [`RootElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpart.rootelement?view=openxml-2.8.1) property instead of `Document` as a starting point to get the `Descendants`.

So the end result would look something like this:

```
var partsToUpdate = new List<OpenXmlPart> { doc.MainDocumentPart }
    .Concat(doc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
    .Concat(doc.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts);

foreach (var part in partsToUpdate)
{
    var elements = part.RootElement
        .Descendants<SdtElement>()
        .Where(s => s.SdtProperties.ChildElements.Count > 0 &&
                    s.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>()?.Val == contentControlTag);

    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var elementText = element.Descendants<Text>();

        if (elementText != null)
        {
            var elementTextValue = elementText.FirstOrDefault();

            if (elementTextValue != null)
            {
                elementTextValue.Text = text;
            }
            elementText.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(t => t.Remove());
        }
    }
}
```